# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi} e^{a\cos(t)}\cos(a\sin t)dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the value of
$$\int_0^{\pi} e^{a\cos(t)}\cos(a\sin t)dt?$$

Comment: Can you please format your question?

Comment: Why are you sure you question has an closed form answer? What context is this from? What techniques do you know? Have you tried putting the sinusoidal functions in exponential form? I see your tag is complex analysis,  so what techniques from that field have you tried?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: the real part of that is $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\color{red}{e^{\cos(at)}}\cos(a\sin t)\,dt$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ah,  thanks for the catch. Messed up on the mental math :/ I'll delete my prior comment.

Answer (score 9):

By exploiting $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right)$ and the Taylor series of the exponential function we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{a\cos t}\cos(a\sin t)\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\left(a e^{it}\right)+\exp(ae^{-it})\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{a^n(e^{nit}+e^{-nit})}{n!}\,dt\end{eqnarray*} $$ 
but the innermost integral always vanishes, unless $n=0$. It follows that $I(a)$ is constant, and
$$ I(0) = \pi $$
is trivial.

Comment: If I set $a > 24.60$ or $a < -24$, Mathematica explodes. Why so?

Comment: @FourierTransform: I think it is a problem in numerical cancellation, that happens by dealing with multiple sine functions with different periods.

Comment: Oh! Thank you and +1!

Comment: @FourierTransform: The same happens if you try to plot $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^2 x)}{n}$$ that is well-defined and continuous for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but heavily non-differentiable.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if you think my answer is too close to yours please give a note and i will delete it...

Comment: @tired: absolutely not. Differentiation under the integral sign is a perfectly sound alternative to series expansion. (+1) back.

Answer (score 4):

The integral may be expressed at

$$\frac12 \operatorname{Re} \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, e^{a e^{i t}} $$

The integral may be written in complex form as, letting $z=e^{i t}$:

$$-i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{e^{a z}}{z} $$

which by Cauchy's integral theorem is simply $2 \pi$.  Thus, the sought-after integral is $\pi$.

Comment: this is a good one... i was trying residue theorem on the original function which becomes way too messy (+1)

Comment: This is how I actually found out the solution. :D

Answer (score 3):

Let us calculate the derivative of the integral $I(a)$ with respect to $a$

$$
I'(a)=\int_0^{\pi}e^{a \cos(t)}\cos(t)\cos(a\sin(t))-\int_0^{\pi}e^{a \cos(t)}\sin(t)\sin(a\sin(t))
$$

applying integration by parts to the second integral with $u'=e^{a \cos(t)}\sin(t)$ and $v=\sin(a\sin(t))$

we get

$$
I'(a)=0
$$

so

$$
I(a)=const
$$

but $I(0)=\pi$ and we end up with

> $$
> I(a)=\pi
> $$

Answer (score 0):

I got a really strange/amusing/interesting response, with Wolfram Mathematica.

In few words, as long as $-24 \leq a \leq 24.60$ the value is:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\ e^{a \cos(t)}\cos(a \sin(t)) \text{d}t = \pi$$

Comment: Yeah,I found out the solution.But why should there be a restriction on a?

Comment: @Rishabhagrawal That is indeed the interesting question!! Great question by the way!