# Integration by part in complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

If we know that $\int_C e^{az}/z dz=2\pi i$ where $C$ is the unit circle with positive orientation; how do I show that $$\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos\theta}\cos(a\sin\theta)d\theta =\pi?$$

I observed that $a\sin\theta$ is the derivative of $a\cos\theta$, so I substituted $a\cos\theta$ with $u$, so the integration becomes $$\int_0^\pi e^u du,$$ but the answer is not $\pi$. Where did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How did you get from the change of variables to concluding that the integrand becomes $\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{u}\,du$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938543/evaluate-int-0-pi-ea-cost-cosa-sin-tdt/1938599#1938599

Comment: @tired could you take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962797/legendre-polynomials-and-cauchy?